# Continous function $r(x)$ on $[0,1]$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n}g(\frac{k}{n},a,b)r(\frac kn)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, summation

The problem is related to this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3073378/edit).

Is there any general way to construct  a non-zero continous function $r(x)$ on $[0,1]$, independent of parameters $a$ and $b$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n}g\left(\frac kn,a,b\right)r\left(\frac kn\right)=0$$ where $g(x,a,b)$ is GIVEN continuous (hence bounded) function on $[0,1]$ with parameters $a,b,$ with $0<a<1$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$.

As an example, we could possibly work with $g(x,a,b)=e^{bx+a}$ though my original $g$ is something else.

Since $g$ is bounded, my intution tells me that there should exist some non-zero $f$ independent of parameters $a,b$ killing that limit.

Comment: What do you mean by independent of $a,b$? Do you want a single function $r(x)$ that works for every possible values of $a,b$?

Comment: @BigbearZzz, Exactly! A single function which works for every $a,b$.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is negative. The conditions can force $r(x)$ to be zero identically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n}g\left(\frac kn,a,b\right)r\left(\frac kn\right)=\int_0^1g(x,a,b)r(x)\, dx,
$$
we want the function $r(x)$ to satisfy 
$$
\int_0^1g(x,a,b)r(x)\, dx=0
$$
for all $(a,b)\in(0,1)\times\Bbb R$. In general, it is **not true** that there would exists a nonzero $r(x)$ with the above property.

Indeed, consider the family of bounded continuous functions
$$
\mathcal F=\left\{ \frac1{1+b^2}+ \sin(x)^{1/a}  :  (a,b)\in(0,1)\times\Bbb R \right\},
$$
it is not hard to see that $D=\{1,\sin(x),\sin(x)^2,\dots\}$ is a subset of $\mathcal F$. According to the [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506912/span-1-sin-t-sin-2t-cdots-is-dense-in-mathscrc0-1?rq=1), the span of $D$ is dense in $C[0,1]$. Since 
$$
\int_0^1 g(x)r(x)\, dx=0
$$
for all $g\in D$, by passing to the limit (using the density result above) we conclude that 
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)r(x)\, dx=0
$$
for all $f\in C[0,1]$. It follows that the only $r(x)$ that works is $r(x)\equiv 0$.

Comment: Wonderful counterexample!! Thank you!  To be specific my $$g=\frac{1}{e^{ax+e^{b-x}}+e^{ax}}$$. My different approach to the problem I am solving, suggests me that there should exist a non-zero $f$ for this choice of $g$. Can we think of such $f$ in this case?

Comment: @ersh Perhaps you should post that as a separate question with that specific  formula for $g(x,a,b)$ and link to this question. Tomorrow I might have a look at it since today I'm tired already. Glad I could help.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you!

Comment: @ersh So if you're happy with this answer please consider accepting it so the question wouldn't be left in the unanswered queue.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot. I am quite well satisfied with your example.